# Need to change the value returned from a mocked static method

Tags: java, powermock

I have a utility class with static methods, something like this:

```
public class Utils
{
  public static String DoSomething(String input)
  {
    String result = null;
    // code does something and puts a value in the result string
    return result;
  }
}
```

In a test case, I mock the class as follows:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);
when(Utils.doSomething(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("SUCCESS");
```

Unfortunately, I need the method return a different value for one of the tests. I added this line to the test:

```
when(Utils.doSomething(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("FAILURE");
```

But when I try to run this, it overrides the method return for all the other tests.

Changing the argument matcher doesn't help because the arguments are the same between tests.

Is there a way for me to tell PowerMock to have the method return the same value for all tests EXCEPT for one?

Comment: You could put the mock in a `@BeforeEach`-method and let it return the "default" value (`"SUCCESS")`. Then move the `when(...)thenReturn("FAILURE")` inside the test where you need a different return value.

Comment: Why do you have a static method that needs to be mocked? What kind of side-effects does it have?

Comment: The method calls an external dependency (essentially a separate service that creates a file), and I want to be able to test twihtout having the service running.

Comment: And why does it need to be static? Your issues here are caused by that and it looks to me like a rather bad code design. Maybe think about making it non-static

Comment: Not my code. I'm just creating unit tests for code that uses it.

Comment: I think you are actually missing a real [mcve]. You see, it really matters how your test class is organized, and where exactly you do those mocking specs.